# Trying to get the Button Value for a List View and Insert Into a Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i am trying to get the button value form a list box and insert it into my data, but my SQL statement cant retrive any value from the button

This is the Button Code

'  Text='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>' CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="addFriend_Click" />

and this is the button on click statment.

```
    protected void addFriend_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the UserId of the just-added user
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        // Insert a new record into UserPro
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        string insertSql = "INSERT INTO User_Friend(ProfileId2, ProfileId1) VALUES( @FriendProfileId) SELECT ProfileId FROM User_Profile WHERE UserId = (@UserId)";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FriendProfileId", ListView1.FindControl("addFriend");
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the Button instance you can it cast from the event param sender.

```
var button = sender as Button;
var text = button.Text;
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but it is inserting the Button Text and not the dynamic value into the database. I want to insert the value instead of the text. many thanks                                      <asp:Button ID="addFriend" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>'  Text="Add Friend" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="addFriend_Click" />